# Found error "not all arguments converted during string formatting" in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I found an error that says

> File "", line 6, in 
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

while I'm trying to implement a `while True` loop in Python. I am trying to identify even and odd numbers with Python. Any suggestion for my problem?

Here's my code:

```
print("Identification Odd/Even number")

while True:
    input = input ('Enter The Number ')
    
    if input %2==0:
        print("Even")
        
    elif input %1==1:
        print("Odd")
        
    next_step = input ('Do you want indetify again? (Yes/No)')
    if next_step == 'No' :
        break
        
    else:
        print('You have input the wrong format')
```

Comment: `input` is a string  You cannot get the remainder of dividing a string by 2.  You need to somehow make input a number.  Also, it's really confusing that you have a variable the same name as a function.

Comment: You need to convert `input` to a number like maybe `elif int(input) %2==1:`

Comment: Owh i see, thnks a lot Jerry

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should not do is, that mixing variable names with function names. The line `input = input('Enter number here: ')` means that in the first pass the function `input()` will no longer be the function you want it to be, instead it will be string you got back from the first loop-pass.
Also you want to go on with some calculations. `input` (the function) will return a string, not an integer.
In order to get an integer from a string you should do a cast `user_input = int(input('Enter number here: '))`.
`user_input` is a integer and you can go on with you modulos operations.
So all in all I suggest based on your code:

- change the **variable name** `input` to something else
- do a cast after retrieving the user first user-input
- for checking if a given number is odd or even there are only two cases to cover, which you can express with if-else-case.
- `input % 1 == 1` will always be `False` because there is no integer that is not divisible by 1.

If you want to continue to ask the user if he wants to go on, you probably want the user to give an answer you specified.
This will need another while-loop.
Why?
If the user gives an arbitrary answer, you want to continue to ask as long as the user gives an apropriate answer.
This is an answer you explicitly asked for.
To do that I have done something like this:

```py
next_step = None
allowed_answers = ['No', 'Yes']
while next_step not in allowed_answer:
    next_step = input('Want to go on? (Yes/No)')
```

If you want to give feedback to the user, something like this solved this riddle for me:

```py
allowed_answers = ['No', 'Yes']
while True:
    next_step = input('Want to go on? (Yes/No)')
    if next_step not in allowed_ansers:
        print('You have input the wrong format')
    else:
        break
```

All in all I would do something like this:

```py
allowed_answers = ['No', 'Yes']
while True:
    user_input = int(input('Enter The Number:'))
            
    if user_input % 2 == 0:
        print("Even")
    else:          
        print("Odd")

    next_step = None
    while next_step not in allowed_answer:
        next_step = input('Do you want indetify again? (Yes/No)')
    if next_step == 'No' :
        break
```

Comment: Thnk u very much, i see that i need use var not same as the function name ..

Comment: I see, so we can use while function if we want user feedback .. i learn so much, thnk u very much

Comment: Also its look like i need to learn more about math operator in python for input  %1==1 lol